# In diagrams, how can I indicate that a body is not moving or rotating?

Tags: classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram, notation, education

I often create diagrams to illustrate the scenario of an exercise for my students. These are not necessarily free-body diagrams, as creating those may be part of the task or similar or it would be overkill. In such diagrams, I can use straight arrows to indicate that a body is moving in a certain direction and circular arrows to indicate rotation. **Is there an established equivalent way to indicate that an object is at rest?**

I am interested in notations for both linear and rotational motion that can be used separately (so I can indicate that a linearly moving body is not rotating and vice versa). My bar for *established* is pretty low, I am happy about anything used by a textbook or proposed in a scientific or didactic journal. It just shouldn’t be an ad-hoc idea to answer this particular question.

What I am mostly using so far is to write $\vec{v}=0$ or similar next to the body, however this has some disadvantages in my opinion:

- It is considerably more complex and requires more space than a simple symbol like the arrow for motion.
- It is inconsistent if I do not use an analogous notation for other moving objects. For example, if I use $v=0$ for a resting object, it is weird that I do not use $v=1\,\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$ for another moving object in the same diagram.
- If I have multiple resting objects in the same diagram, I would need to use $v_1 = 0$, $v_2=0$, etc. to be precise.
- Making the step from *body at rest* to $v=0$ is among the (very basic) things my students should learn to do by themselves.

Comment: Can it not just be stated in the text of the exercise, I'm guessing it would confuse more people if you include more notation than is necessary to make a clear diagram.

Comment: @Triatticus: Of course, all the information would also be in the text, but diagrams are very useful to communicate everything in a separate way and thus avoid misunderstanding and just communicate things clearly. I totally agree that introducing such a notation for just a single diagram would be more confusing than anything, but for an entire mechanics course, I would estimate that I have thirty occurrences in the exercises alone, on top of which you have usage in lectures, exercise sessions, etc.

Comment: You probably don't need to be too formal about it. Here is an example where the diagram conveys the idea. [Asteroid as a "free slingshot?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200085/37364)

Comment: Would you be able to adopt a convention that any object that with linear motion will have a straight arrow, and any rotating object will have a circular arrow, (maybe use a helical arrow for an object rotating and linearly moving?), so that the *absence* of an arrow can be taken to *imply* that the object is not moving? Perhaps you would need to introduce a symbol for "state of motion unknown", for example in problems involving static friction.

Comment: @Andrew: I can, but that is dissatisfying as well, since it comes with all the downsides of communication by omission, in particular, people cannot be sure I that I didn’t make a mistake (until they read the text).